# When is "obj instanceof Object" false in Java?

Tags: java

Consider

```
 Object obj = ....;
 System.out.println(obj instanceof Object);
```

What should obj be so that the answer is `false` (Any other option other than `null`)

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything extends Object, so you will always get true here (unless obj is null).

Answer (score 40):

Is this a trick question?

```
Object obj = new Object() {{ System.out.println(false); System.exit(0); }};
System.out.println(obj instanceof Object);
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what does the double-brace signify?

Comment: The double brace idiom. The outer brace is the syntax for an anonymous inner class (in this case not defining any methods). The inner brace is an instance initialiser (becomes part of the constructor).

Comment: Unfortunately, this prints 'false' on creation, not when doing the instanceof check ;)

Answer (score 11):

This will print false:

```
public final class Foo {
    static private final class Object {
    }

    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.lang.Object o = new java.lang.Object();
        System.out.println(o instanceof Object);
    }
}
```

It's not *quite* what you asked for, but the best I could think of...

Answer (score 9):

This will **never** return false if `obj` is non-null

Answer (score 0):

Every object descends from 'Object'. Your statement will **always** be true.

Answer (score 0):

None AFAIK. Did you get this as an interview question?

[By definition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#80289), it should return true if you can cast the variable into an Object, and all non-nulls should be convertible. Perhaps there is some trick with generics, but I doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

**The only way to make it false is not to give it an object, give it a null reference**

Discussed **[here](http://hanuska.blogspot.com/2006/08/tricky-instanceof-operator.html)**

Comment: "What should be obj so that the answer is false (Any other option other than null)"

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if `Object` refers to `java.lang.Object` (as defined by the boot classloader) this is not possible as every class in the process must descend from `java.lang.Object`

However you can define something else called `Object` in an inner scope, hiding `java.lang.Object`.

Here's an example where the name `Object` refers to `java.lang.Object` at the start of a method and a local class later:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object value = "42"; class Object {}
    System.out.println(value instanceof Object);
}
```

This is a slight cheat because the declaration of `value` is not a single statement but a statement followed by a local class definition.

I tested this in Eclipse 3.5.0, but I wouldn't be surprised if other compilers behave differently with a pathological example like this.

Comment: Why the mess with the generic class? This does the same: `public static void main(String[] args) { Object v = (Object)"42"; class Object {} System.out.println(v instanceof Object); }`

Comment: @Atmocreations, it's a while since I wrote this but for some reason I assumed that wouldn't compile.  I prefer your example (the simpler the better) & I've updated mine to match.

Comment: hmm right. haven't seen that the post is quite old :D well didn't wanna criticize you. when I saw your code, I had to try it :P Compiles and runs from the command line, therefore this has nothing to do with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Old, old question but:

- if obj is null
- if you use jview back in late 90s and trying Variant (don't recall the package by heart).

Answer (score 0):

It could also be an instance of a primitive object like int, double, boolean, etc. If do so, it'll probably return false as well