# Object universal superclass java instanceof

Tags: java, object, superclass, instanceof

Can someone provide an explanation for when `(x instancef Object)` will not equal true? Here's the full question?

> `Object` is the universal superclass in Java, a superclass of all other classes. However, the expression `x instanceof Object` does not always equal true. Devise a declaration for `x` to demonstrate this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is "obj instanceof Object" false in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341455/when-is-obj-instanceof-object-false-in-java)

Comment: Also remember that instanceOf does compile time checking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` is not an instance of any class, and therefore returns `false` to the use of the `instanceof` operator:

```
Object x = null;
if (!x instanceof Object) {
    System.out.println ("we get here since X is null");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the `null` answer is the "correct one". But here is a pedantic alternative:

```
public class Test {

  private class Object {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.lang.Object s = new String("foo");    
    System.out.println((s instanceof Object));
  }
}
```

Prints

```
false
```

Here we abuse that fact that `Object` does not always refer to `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is `null`, `instanceof` will return `false`.

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate of [When is “obj instanceof Object” false in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341455/when-is-obj-instanceof-object-false-in-java)

If `Object a=null;` then `a instanceof Object` returns `false`

Comment: Then don't answer. Flag as a duplicate and move on.